# Why my code outputs false, what happens at if(c>b>a)?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30;
if (c > b > a)
    printf("TRUE");
else
    printf("FALSE");
return 0;
}
```

What happens at if(c>b>a), i know this works like if((c>b)>a),but why then false?

Comment: `c > b` is either 1 or 0 (in your case, it's 1). You want `c > b && b > a`.

Comment: How would you evaluate ((c>b)>a) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator `>` is left associative therefore `c > b > a`  will be parenthesize as `((c > b) > a)` . Since `30` is greater than `20`, `c > b = 1`. So,

```
 (c > b) > a => (1 > a) => 1 > 10 => false
```

Answer (score 1):

`c>b` evaluates to 1, which is not greater than 10.

Answer (score 1):

`c > b > a` means

`(c > b) > a` which is false in your case..